# How to reduce this lines in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many lines of code in this way and how to reduce these lines. Also please explain ur code. If any easy way of writing such logical codes pls post the links.

```
$(function () {
  $("#menu1").click(function () {
    $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)"});
    $("#menu2").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
    $("#menu3").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
    $("#menu4").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
    $("#menu5").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
  });

  $("#menu2").click(function () {
    $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)"});
    $("#menu1").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
    $("#menu3").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
    $("#menu4").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
    $("#menu5").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
  });

  $("#menu3").click(function () {
    $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)"});
    $("#menu1").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
    $("#menu2").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
    $("#menu4").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
    $("#menu5").css({"background-color": "transparent"});
  });
});
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

Use jquery [`Attribute starts with selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/%3anot/). Try this:

```
$(function(){
     $("[id^=menu]").click(function(){
          $(this).css({"background-color":"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)"});
          $("[id^=menu]").not(this).css({"background-color":"transparent"});   
     });            
});
```

Comment: May be simpler to set `background-color:transparent` to all, and then apply the `rgba(..)` colour to the `this` element.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Yes It is simple to set `backgorund-color:transparent` to all and then apply `rgba(..)` to this element. But If OP wants to add any other css to `this` element OP can use .not().

Comment: I still think my way's easier :p `$("[id^=menu]").css({"background-color":"transparent"});` followed by `$(this).css({"background-color":"rgba(255,255,255,0.4)","other-css":"value-here"...})`

Answer (score 4):

Give all of the menus a common class and do this

```
$('.menu').on('click',function(){
    $('.menu').css({"background-color":"transparent"});
    $(this).css({"background-color":"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)"});
});
```